# How to keep the state of a css based navigation menu while navigating to other pages

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am new to CSS and trying to find out how to keep the state of a css based menu over multiple pages.

The situation is like this
I am working on an intranet site.
There is a set structure of the website. I have content files and a left menu file. The left menu file is used for creating links to other pages and it is imported in all the content files. (these are ASP files and I am not sure what we call it technically for using the content of one file in all the other files).

So the task is that I have a site map and I want to translate it into the links in the left menu file so that they appear in all the content pages.

I am using [this example](http://www.skypoet.net/examples/TreeList/treelist.html) and adjusted it for my needs. The problem is when I go from one page to the other the state of the expanded and collapsed nodes does not stay the same. What is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: 1. displaying content in an iframe so when you go to another page the menu tree does not refresh; 2. using javascript or jquery to compare your url if contain certain characters (menu title etc.) then set menu node display accordingly

Comment: I think iframe is better in my situation. I will try to make it work with an iframe.